APS Environment Entitlement isn’t included in the app signature’s entitlements
I have uploaded a build of my IOS app to appstore but I got an email from Apple
This is for your information only and doesn't require any action:
ITMS-90078: Missing potentially required entitlement - Your app, or a library that’s included in your app, uses Apple Push Notification service (APNs) registration APIs, but the APS Environment Entitlement isn’t included in the app signature’s entitlements. If your app uses APNs, make sure the App ID is enabled for push notifications in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, sign the app with a distribution provisioning profile that includes the APS Environment Entitlement, and upload a new build to ensure that push notifications function as intended. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering-your-app-with-apns.
Apple Developer Relations
I have added push notifications capability in general and certificate but still getting this email with every upload and getting never subscribed in push notification in onesignal dashboard and also this message Status details: Missing Push Capability
my app is developed on flutter
